# remove/add code not applying on index.php

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the following code to affect the navigation elements on my homepage.

```
    if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
// Default homepage
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) {
    $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg-fill');
    $('#nav-btns').removeClass('white').addClass('black');
  } else {
    $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg-fill');
    $('#nav-btns').removeClass('black').addClass('white');
 }
});

}
```

with my navigation looking like

```
<nav id="anim-nav" class="row">

        <div id="nav-btns" class="col-sm-8">
               <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'screen-nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

 ...
```

css

```
.bg-fill { background: #fff; }
.white { color: #fff;}
.black { color: #333;}
```

I want to basically make my links white at the top of the page then black when the user scrolls. But ONLY on the home page. Everywhere else I want them to stay the same (originally black)

Everything I try seems to apply on all the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first bunch of code seems to mix php and js. So after your condition, you should add a closing php tag and add an opening tag after your js code.

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) { ?>
// Default homepage
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) {
    $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg-fill');
    $('#nav-btns').removeClass('white').addClass('black');
  } else {
    $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg-fill');
    $('#nav-btns').removeClass('black').addClass('white');
 }
});
<?php
}
```

Comment: Doing that removes the functionality of the navigation